# Why should one use a single-use temporary variable?

Tags: programming-languages, language-agnostic, coding-standards

Let's say we have a class called 'Automobile' and we have an instance of that class called 'myCar'. I would like to ask why do we need to put the values that our methods return in a variable? Why don't we just call the method?

For example, why should one write:

```
string message = myCar.SpeedMessage();
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

instead of:

```
Console.WriteLine(myCar.SpeedMessage());
```

Comment: The only time I would do that would be if `SpeedMessage` was an expensive operation and its value was going to be used multiple times.

Answer (score 52):

Short answer: We don't. Both examples are absolutely fine.

There are three reasons why people use temporary variables anyway (like in your first example):

1. It gives an explicit name to the intermediate value (we now know that it's a `message`, not just any old string).
2. It helps prevent statements getting too long and too complex.
3. It makes step-debugging easier, because you can step over each part individually (although there are step debuggers that work at sub-line precision).

Comment: @Timwi Disagree. I'd move #2 up to #1. Writing code in simple, easy to read steps is an excellent habit, and using local variables as needed facilitates that.

Comment: +1 excellent points.  I always argue *for* point #1 - naming it explicitly allows you to describe the variable's **intent**, which is basically the only information missing (your IDE can do the rest: inform you of the type, navigate to source, etc).

Comment: 4. There used to be an extra step in between creating the variable and the (now) only use of it, that was removed for some reason.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that many optimizers will elide the variable, so if you go looking for it in the debugger, it may not exist.  Not a problem if you compile with the debug flag set, but at higher optimization levels that's a pretty common optimization.

Comment: Re: "Explicit name to intermediate value" - in the example above, `speedMessage()` is *more* descriptive than just `message`.  I would think that when possible, it would be better to improve the name of a method being called than to introduce a temporary variable.  When that's not possible, a temporary variable *or a comment* can aid readability.  But I'm with you on #2 and #3.

Answer (score 4):

in most languages you don't need to which is handy if you want to use a getter and pass it into a method:

```
bar.doBaz(faa.getFoo())
```

but it can improve readability by separating the calls especially when it's a non trivial function

also it reduces the horizontal footprint of the call at the cost of an extra line (provided that the new variable's name is short)

Answer (score 4):

There are some times when an extra variable can help general readability, especially when evaluating some long expression inside an `if` or a function call that makes the code go way off the right-hand side of the screen.

In Java 5 or later (and many similar languages), an extra variable can be useful to find the cause of null-pointer exceptions.  Consider the following Java code which relies on Java's "autoboxing" to convert `Integer` objects to an `int` primitive:

```
public int add(Integer firstIntObj, Integer secondIntObj) {
    return firstIntObj + secondIntObj;
}
```

It will throw a NullPointerException when it converts an uninitialized (`null`) `Integer` object into a primitive `int`, but this exception doesn't indicate which object caused the exception because the two possible culprits are on the same line.  The following would blow up on a different line for each `null` input, thus the line number in the exception will indicate which one was `null`:

```
public int add(Integer firstIntObj, Integer secondIntObj) {
    int first = firstIntObj;
    int second = secondIntObj;
    return first + second;
}
```

A better way to handle this is to throw your own descriptive exception so that someone calling this method can diagnose their own problem without needing your source code:

```
public int add(Integer firstIntObj, Integer secondIntObj) {
    if (firstIntObj == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("First argument was null!");
    }
    if (secondIntObj == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second argument was null!");
    }
    return firstIntObj + secondIntObj;
}
```

This technique can be used to split up any line that could throw more than one exception.  Using separate variables is less typing than throwing a descriptive exception - it's quick and dirty.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it doesn't really matter but when you're working with bigger systems it can be an issue as:

1. It makes debugging a lot easier
2. If you have a habit of compacting your code as far as me it makes it actually readable ie:

`square(getNum1(var1,var2[(param1+(param2%2))]),obj1.getNum2(((ptr1+dynamicOffset1)+5)(getMult(NULL))))`

Comment: You might want to expand on the "makes debugging easier" statement, by explaining how some (all?) debuggers make it hard to set a breakpoint in the middle of a statement. Using two lines means it's possible to set a break after the variable has been assigned but before the value is used in the following statement.